# De onde vem a palavra "arreda"?

Tags: etimologia, verbos

Sou de Minas Gerais e a palavra "arreda" sempre foi muito comum na minha vida.

Para a minha surpresa, contudo, descobri que essa palavra não é tão difundida pelo resto do Brasil (em relação às outras nações lusófonas não tenho nem ideia). Muitas pessoas não sabem o que é "arreda".

Então fico na dúvida: de onde veio essa palavra? Veio da região de MG mesmo?

---

De uma simples, porém correta, definição encontrada no Google:

> **Arreda:**
>
> Designa comando para alguém se arredar ou se afastar; para trás, afaste-se.

Comment: A palavra é conhecida em Portugal. Há uma música muito conhecida, [Indo Eu](http://alfarrabio.di.uminho.pt/cancioneiro/html/129.html), que tem no refrão «(...) ora chega, chega, chega / ora **arreda** lá pra trás».

Comment: Já ouvi "arreda" algumas vezes, principalmente sob a forma "humm, esse cara não arreda pé daqui" (não sai daqui) mas não é uma palavra corriqueira no Rio de Janeiro.

Comment: Minha mãe que é do interior do Paraná sempre fala "Arredar os móveis para fazer a limpeza"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com o [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/arreda), a interjeição *arreda*, com o significado de sair, como em «Arreda daí!», vem do imperativo do verbo [*arredar*](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/arredar/), com mais significados. Já o verbo *arredar* vem do castelhano *arredrar*, que provavelmente vem do latim *ad retro* (para trás).